# OpenCV Mat crashes while push_back

Tags: c++, c, opencv, mat

I am trying to create a matrix of the following in OpenCV by using the push_back function.

```
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;
 1, 1, 1;
 1, 1, 1]
```

This following code works.

**Code I**

```
Mat matrix( 0, 3, CV_32F ); 
Mat zero  = Mat::zeros( 2, 3, CV_32F ); 
Mat one   = Mat::ones( 2, 3, CV_32F ); 
matrix.push_back( zero ); 
matrix.push_back( one );
```

But the following will result in crashes.

**Code II**

```
Mat matrix( 0, 3, CV_32F ); 
matrix.push_back( Mat::zeros( 2, 3, CV_32F ) ); 
matrix.push_back( Mat::ones( 2, 3, CV_32F ) );
```

According to [OpenCV documentation about push_back](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back),

```
template<typename T> void Mat::push_back(const T& elem)
```

The only requirement is "the type of elem and the number of columns must be the same as in the container matrix". And I think **Code II** meets the requirement. Can anybody explain why **Code II** will result in crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's interesting, maybe even a bug.

- Code1 calls void Mat::push_back(const Mat& elems),
- Code2 calls void Mat::push_back(const _Tp& elem) , which is clearly broken. it seems to get the MatExpr returned from Mat::zeros() wrong ( because it's non-const ? )

well, this one works, too ( but it's clearly not , what you wanted )

```
    Mat matrix( 0, 3, CV_32F ); 
    matrix.push_back( Mat( Mat::zeros( 2, 3, CV_32F) ) ); 
    matrix.push_back( Mat( Mat::ones( 2, 3, CV_32F ) ) ); 
    cerr << matrix << endl;
```

maybe [make an issue here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues)

Comment: I just checked. Mat::zeros() and Mat::ones() do not return matrixes, but instead, they return arrays of 0s and 1s respectively. Could that be the reason? I am still not so sure whether it is a bug.

Comment: Mat::zeros() and ones() return a [MatExpr](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-zeros) . it should be easily assignable to a Mat, but something clearly goes wrong in the example you posted. and yes, quite understandable, that you don't want to make a fool of yourself there, but no fear, the devs there don't bite, so if you don't feel like, i'll probably do. (bugs only go away, if you *tell* them ... )